# Fluid Sim not working when using a small flow object

Tags: fluid-simulation

So i'm trying to create a fluid sim, using a UV sphere as the flow. I have added a cube as a domain, following CG Geek's tutorial. However, when I scale the flow object down to a small size, it does not produce the simulation whatsoever. I'm wondering if there is a setting that needs to be changed to allow smaller objects to emit water?

I've tried scaling up the other objects in my scene, but this is a lot more complex than scaling down the flow object. It also seems to be that the flow object has a cutoff point where it no longer seems to produce the liquid.

I've added an image to show my scene currently. The flow object is small, but I only need a small trickle of water to be produced, as eventually, the water will be emitted from inside the horns of the character.

Any solutions/workarounds are greatly appreciated.

Side note: The scene will be rendered as a still image and not an animation if this makes things any easier in terms of fixes.

[image]

Comment: the smaller your object is, the higher the resolution must be - but be aware - this will slow down your computer and needs loooong time to render